# PHP multi array search and assign value to variable

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have searched the forums up and down, tested as much as I can and still cannot find an answer to this problem.  I need to assign a value to the following variables:

```
$custID           = contactId;
$custFieldCityID  = [customFieldValues][x][customFieldId]
$custFieldCity    = [customFieldValues][x][value][x]
$custFieldStateID = [customFieldValues][x][customFieldId]
$custFieldState   = [customFieldValues][x][value][x]
```

**The order of the customFieldValues always changes (city can be in position 2, next array is in position 0, etc) and the customFieldId value is always different.**

Here is the array I am getting (cannot be changed):

```
Array
(
    [contactId] => V
    [name] => Mrs Mder
    [email] => xxx@verizon.net
    [customFieldValues] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [customFieldId] => I
                    [name] => city
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Fairfax
                        )

                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Fairfax
                        )

                    [type] => text
                    [fieldType] => text
                    [valueType] => string
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [customFieldId] => 8
                    [name] => postal_code
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 22032
                        )

                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 22032
                        )

                    [type] => text
                    [fieldType] => text
                    [valueType] => string
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [customFieldId] => M
                    [name] => state
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => VA
                        )

                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => VA
                        )

                    [type] => text
                    [fieldType] => text
                    [valueType] => string
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [customFieldId] => V
                    [name] => street
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123 Holden Street
                        )

                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123 Holden Street
                        )

                    [type] => text
                    [fieldType] => text
                    [valueType] => string
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [customFieldId] => s
                    [name] => phone
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => +11234567890
                        )

                    [values] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => +11234567890
                        )

                    [type] => text
                    [fieldType] => text
                    [valueType] => phone
                )

        )
)
```

So far I have tried this:

```
foreach($returncustdata as $row) {
       foreach($row as $k) {
            $fieldID= $k['customFieldValues']['customFieldId'];
            $fieldname = $k['customFieldValues']['name'];
            $fieldvalue = $k['customFieldValues']['value'][0];
       }
}
```

Comment: Well one way to do this obviously is to simply write an according number of conditions, `if ($k['customFieldValues']['name'] == 'city') { $custFieldCity = $k['customFieldValues']['value'][0]; }`, etc. Or use a `switch` statement instead. If the names of the variables you want to create can always be derived from the `name` property, you could also use _variable variables_ (although those are a rather unclean concept.)

Answer (score 0):

You can index your `customFieldValues` by `name` for simpler access:

1. Use [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#example-4923) with 2nd argument `null` and 3rd argument `name` to index that array by `name` field making it associative array.
2. To get first element from array no matter of it's key you can use [`current()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php). If it's always in 0th position, then no need for this.

```php
$myArray['customFieldValues'] = array_column($myArray['customFieldValues'], null, 'name');

$custID           = $myArray['contactId'];
$custFieldCityID  = $myArray['customFieldValues']['city']['customFieldId'];
$custFieldCity    = current($myArray['customFieldValues']['city']['value']);
$custFieldStateID = $myArray['customFieldValues']['state']['customFieldId'];
$custFieldState   = current($myArray['customFieldValues']['state']['value']);
```